# Finding missing or skipped FIDs in a large list of features

Tags: shapefile, attribute-table, fields-attributes, identify

I have a shapefile containing 2454 features each with their own unique ID (FID), however the highest FID is 2578. Some features were merged during processing, causing their original FID to disappear. For example, the FID count goes 1531, 1532, 1533, 1538.

I would like to know a way to identify the missing FIDs without having to scroll through thousands of features and noting the missing numbers. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: The "fid" of a shapefile is the record number. It's not possible to skip values. If, by "shapefile" you mean "any geodata", then it would depend on the actual geodata storage format (and probably require copying the contents to a new feature class).

Comment: As Vince says, the FID of a shapefile is always going to be a row count from 0 to x.  It sounds like during your processing you ended up with an attribute storing the FIDs from the original data.  Maybe post a picture of your attributes, list what kind of featureclass you have, and what software you are using.

Comment: When a shape is deleted it can be marked as deleted into the .dbf file but it is not necessary to remove it physically. When shapefile is at that status the record numbers can have holes. The holes disappear when the shapefile is "repacked". There is some documentation about this in https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/shapefile.html. Search "repack".

Answer (score 4):

You must be mentioning `FID` column, not automatically generated ID.

In QGIS, you can get the missing values using the following script:

```py
ids = [f["FID"] for f  in iface.activeLayer().getFeatures()]

print("Missing ids")
for i in range(0, max(ids)):
    if i not in ids:
        print(i)
```